# bootstrap carousel with dynamic values to submit userid to another form

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap

I am having twitter bootstrap carousel with images coming from database

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
           <div class="item active">
              <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="zero" width="100%" min-height="10%"/>
              <div class="carousel-caption"><p>ABCD</p></div>
           </div>
          <?php
           session_start();
          $link=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
          $database="db_name";
          $db_found=mysql_select_db($database,$link);
          $insert=mysql_query("select p.profile_image_path, u.name,u.user_ID from profile p, users u where p.email=u.email");
          $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($insert);
          for ($i=0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) { 
          while($data = mysql_fetch_row($insert)){
            $_SESSION['userid']=$data[2]; /*<img src="'.$data[0].'" alt="zero"  />?id='.$data[2].'&role=2*/
          echo '<div class="item"><form method="POST" action="/Profile">
          <a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">
          <input type="image" name="carc" src="'.$data[0].'" />
          <input type="hidden" name="car" value="'.$data[2].'">
          </a></form><div class="carousel-caption"><p>'.$data[1].'</p></div></div>';
            }
          }
              ?>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and I want to link to the profile page of particular user when clicked on the image of carousel....
but in actual with POST method it is submitting only 1st value of loop
and if I use SESSION it gives the last value of loop..

Please help me... thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

got the solution by my own..... Instead of

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();return false;">
```

I should have used

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms[].submit();return false;">
```